# Unable to connect to SO from work

Tags: support, stack-overflow

At work, all week I was unable to connect to SO.  I have received confirmation that the site has not been blocked either.

I get a 403 page ... {FF && IE}

What should I try to do to resolve this issue??

Comment: Talk to your network managers. They've blocked the site.

Comment: Even if I was told no ??

Comment: It seems that the default gateway values were not set right ....

Answer (score 2):

Careful with recommendations like Anonymouse.  Where I work, tunneling out like this will get you walked out the door and your things sent home in a box.  You may rail about it being nonsense, but if that's the policy of your employer you have to either live with it or find a new place to work.

There are two ways to view looking at SO at work:

1. You're merely using it as a source for answers to tough programming questions that you encounter during the day.  Your employer is likely to support that.
2. You're spending time answering questions, building your reputation, and using time that you're getting paid to do something else.  Your employer is likely to frown on that.

I can see SO from my desk, but I never log on.  I don't want to be tempted.  I wait 'til I return home to waste my own time.  8)

Comment: Actually, building rep can help you raise bounty to answer tough question.

Comment: I go on SO at work to browse and see what others are doing/asking. I also have like nothing to really do so browsing SO is a good thing for me. Also, my employer doesn't mind -- it's educational :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH to your home computer (and allowed to do so) you can set up a proxy server like squid at home. Then at work you do this

```
ssh -f -L localhost:3128:localhost:3128 youruser@yourcomputer sleep 600
```

In your browser, use localhost:3128 as the proxy server. Your home proxy will even work if it only accepts connections from localhost. Also useful if you are on an unsafe wifi network.